# switching between activities in android

Tags: android, android-intent

My code for a button click of first activity is

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String text=e1.getText().toString();
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), editview.class);
        i.putExtra("mytext", text);
        CustomListViewAndroidExample.this.startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

and second activity code is

```
et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
et1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("mytext"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text=e1.getText().toString();
            Intent i=new Intent(CustomListViewAndroidExample.this, editview.class);
            i.putExtra("mytext", text);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried that already but when I click on that button  I get the message "Application Stopped working"

Comment: Can you paste your full xml file or log.

Comment: I fix that, but text not copy from first activity to second one

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the info as such

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    language = bundle.getString("Language");
```

setting it as so

```
  language="bla";
    intent.putExtra("Language", language);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Ya, its working...:)
Can you tell me how can I set font style of Items of list view to "Marathi.ttf"

Comment: This is how to change fonts, use it in your line xml.